# Cannot Offline-Exporting highchart Treemap to PDF

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I can't Offline-Exporting highchart Treemap to PDF, but PNG, JPEG, SVG can work well. (version 9.3.0)

Use Online-Exporting can works well too.

There has an error in Console:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. offline-exporting.js:23

Here's my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [
    {
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Apple',
                id: 'Apple',
                value: 75.09627342252769,
            },
            {
                name: 'Banana',
                id: 'Banana',
                value: 9.52872657747232,
            },
            {
                name: 'Watermelon and Grape',
                id: 'Watermelon and Grape',
                value: 4.157502418100004,
            },
            {
                name: 'Pomegranate/Cherry',
                id: 'Pomegranate/Cherry',
                value: 3.5141563985028808,
            },
            {
                name: 'Strawberry',
                id: 'Strawberry',
                value: 2.1298309432692712,
            },
            {
                name: 'Peach/pear',
                id: 'Peach/pear',
                value: 2.078751209050002,
            },
            {
                name: 'Mulberry',
                id: 'Mulberry',
                value: 2.0722854199083227,
            },
            {
                name: 'Sponge Cream and Fruit',
                id: 'Sponge Cream and Fruit',
                value: 1.4224736111695193,
            },
        ],
    },
],
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Treemap',
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Test Export',
},
});
```

Here's the demo online: https://jsfiddle.net/whpLg92u/1/

Comment: You provided code and example but it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve. Try to improve this question.

Comment: Hi @amanda, This problem looks like a Highcharts regression bug from version 9.0.0 (it works fine in version 8: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nx0cgf7t/). You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues